# How can I use DBNull.Value with datagridview cells?

Tags: c#, insert

I have this method which inserts data from a `Datagridview` in a table in my db , It works fine if all cells in my `Datagridview` are not `Null` but , If some cells are empty or null it throws the error :

> The parameterized query expects the parameter , which was not supplied

The fact is some of cells can be null and the db will accept that , The required cells I need already forced to be filled by the user , So the optional cells could be null .

My method:

```
private void InsertAll()
{
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Cn.ConnectionString)) // Using block around the connection
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("", cn))
    {

        cmd.CommandText = @" INSERT INTO Transactions ( DocNum, Code, QtyIn, QtyOut, BalanceAfter, Remarks, Unit )
                     Values (@DocNum, @Code, @QtyIn, @QtyOut, @BalanceAfter, @Remarks,@Unit);";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocNum", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QtyIn", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QtyOut", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BalanceAfter", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);

        var qtyKey = (txtTransType.Text == "Release") ? "@QtyOut" : "@QtyIn";

        for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // These are 3 key fields which can't be null and I force the user to fill .
            // So no need to check if null cause it always will have some value .
            
            cmd.Parameters["@DocNum"].Value = txtDocNum.Text;
            cmd.Parameters["@Code"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Code"].Value;
            cmd.Parameters[qtyKey].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Qty"].Value;

            // The rest is the optional cells that the db accepts to be null

            // Then I need to check if they are null and pass the DBNull.Value .            

            // Try DBValue.Null
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV1.CurrentRow.Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value.ToString()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value;
            }
            // Another Try

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Remarks.ToString()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Remarks"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Remarks"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value;
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Unit.ToString()))
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Unit"].Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Unit"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Unit"].Value;
            }

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

This part :

```
  if   (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DGV1.CurrentRow.Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value;
                    }
```

Throws error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of object

I tried also This :

```
 if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Remarks.ToString()))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@Remarks"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@Remarks"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value;
                }
```

But causes the original error as if it doesn't exist at all .
Appreciate your help , Thanks

Comment: When your cell is empty it can return null. So here `DGV1.CurrentRow.Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value.ToString()` you call ToString on something that might be null. You should explicitly check for null before doing something with value.

Comment: You wouldn't need to worry about it if you used a SqlDataAdapter to track the data and make changes. [Here is an example](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid) if you are interested.

Comment: @Ralf Thanks for replying , It can't be done without using `ToString` `Cannot convert object to string`

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for your reply , I'm using `SqlDataadapter` if the datagridview was bound to data source it is easier for me to update data , But with insert or delete i use this way .

Comment: Adapters can handle SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, as shown in the example. You can change the example to use MS SQL Server just by replacing all instances of "Sqlite.." with "Sql...".

Comment: @CsharpNewbie if your object is null you can't call to ToString. null.ToString() is invalid. You must first test for null and then you might call to ToString in the non null case. So used correctly it is surely possibly.

Comment: @Crowcoder It is a good example thanks for it , I will try it sometime .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works guys , Simple null check without using string methods

```
  if (DGV1.CurrentRow.Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value == null)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value;
                    }
```

Thanks all